# Return a MySQL result, with results formated as JSON, with row id as the JSON key for each row result

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

A query like this:

`SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'tag', tag)) from all_tags;`

produces a result like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 979,
        "tag": "alternative"
    },
    {
        "id": 947,
        "tag": "ambient"
    }
]
```

The above is ok, but what I really want is to get a result like this:

```
[
    979:{
        "tag": "alternative"
    },
    947: {
        "tag": "ambient"
    }
]
```

Is this possible to do only using mysql?

I've tried `SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(id, JSON_OBJECT( 'tag', tag))) from all_tags;`

This does allow me to nest columns as a value for a row id. But it doesn't really help as the key is still nested in an object.

Ultimately I'm hoping to use the result as a map in Javacript to look up properties by key. I could shape the data in JS, I'm just curious if it can be done with MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show is not valid JSON. If you use the square brackets `[ ]` then it's just an array, not an object. But if you use the `key: value` format, that's an object, not an array.

I think the following comes closer to what you want:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(id, JSON_OBJECT( 'tag', tag)) from all_tags;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was always running into errors when I tried stuff like that.

Your answer, as is, gives an error too, but it's perfect after removing the extra closing bracket.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't test it. I've edited to fix the extra paren.

Comment: No need to apologize. Was banging my head on the wall and this let me see the light. Thanks again.